# How to setValue in element while iterating through them in nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I want to fill some input field automatically using nightwatch. But getting some error. The error is like:

```
 Running Test on own site:
 Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: The supplied argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS). – invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was s...
```

> This is my html file code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="inp">
        <input type="text" class="inp">
        <input type="text" class="inp">
        <input type="text" class="inp">
        <input type="text" class="inp">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Below is my test.js File Code .

```
module.exports ={
          "Test on own site":function(browser){
          browser.url('http://127.0.0.1:5500/files/index.html')
          .pause(2000);
        browser.elements('xpath','//input[@type="text"]',function(results){
            results.value.forEach((ele,index)=>{
              console.log(index);
              browser.setValue(ele.ELEMENT,index);  // i want to set the value of each input element.
            })
        })
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done that in this way:

```
module.exports = {
"Test on own site": function(browser) {
    browser.url('http://127.0.0.1:5500/files/index.html')
        .pause(2000);
      browser.elements('css selector','input',(results)=>{
      console.log(results.value.length);
      results.value.forEach((element,index)=>{
        browser.elementIdValue(element.ELEMENT,index).pause(2000);
      })
    }).pause(2000);        
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. I can think of three scenarios in which it can fail -

1)You have a slow internet connection, in this case, please retry.

2)Increase the value of pause to `4000` and then retry.

3)Use a CSS selector instead of Xpath.

```
module.exports = {
    "Test on own site": function(browser) {
        browser.url('http://127.0.0.1:5500/files/index.html')
            .pause(4000);
        browser.elements('css selector', 'input[type="text"]', function(results) {
            results.value.forEach((ele, index) => {
                console.log(index);
                browser.setValue(ele.ELEMENT, index); // i want to set the value of each input element.
            })
        })
    }

}
```